# Reference overridden method in supertype constructor

Tags: java

I'm trying to find a solution for a project assignment. Basically I have created a class which is derivative of another abstract class. In it's construction I'm trying to call the supertype constructor with a string and an integer as argument. The issue is that I'm trying to calculate the integer value in an overridden method in the same class. Like so:

```
super(name, getBaseValue());
```

This doesn't work because I can't reference the method within the supertype constructor. Maybe I have simply misunderstood the assignment and the UML-diagram. Any ideas how to go about solving this?

Comment: You can call static methods before the super constructor but not actual object methods. However, we cannot help you with understanding what the instructor wanted from you as you haven't been giving sufficient details for this.

Answer (score 2):

getBaseValue() must be static and also use this.getBaseValue (), so that it looks like this:
super(name, this.getBaseValue());

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't do that at all. At the time the constructor runs, the object is not yet created (it's still in the process of being created), and calling a method on it is risky because that method may assume the object is fully created. Even worse, a derived class could also define that method, and then you the parent constructor isn't even done when a child class' method is already called --- chaos.

You can call static methods (which don't require an object instance being created), or you can hard-code any values you want to pass.

See also [MET05-J. Ensure that constructors do not call overridable methods](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/MET05-J.+Ensure+that+constructors+do+not+call+overridable+methods) in the Secure Java Coding Standard and [Sonar Source's warning](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1699) about this.